# How to call smart contract functions with an address stored in hardware wallet?

Tags: contract-invocation, hardware-wallets

Is there a way to call smart contract functions with an address stored in hardware wallet? If so, please let me know how. Thanks.

Comment: It's a pity no one answered - I have the same question. Have you found an answer by any chance?